# Dividir widget na tela

Tags: android, android-layout, widget

To querendo dividir dois **widget** dentro do **LayoutLinear**, sendo os dois **TextView** .

Se eu utilizar **"orientation="horizontal"** e no **TextView** utilizar o atributo `android:layout_weight="1"`, os widgets ficaram dividos na tela em uma proporção de 50% para cada um!

Então minha dúvida é :

> Existe alguma forma de dividir esses dois widgets na tela em proporções diferentes? como por exemplo 20% da tela pra um e 80% pro outro?
>
> > Isso sem usar medidas prontas 
> >     como por exemplo, a tela tem 300px, dai determino que um terá 100px e o outro 200px

Comment: Ivan, você pode usar números fracionários ou números maiores que um como peso, um caso bacana seria colocar o `LinearLayout` com `weightSum="5"` e distribuir os pesos entre 2 e 3 entre as suas duas Views.

Comment: @Wakim dessa forma funcionou perfeitamente! Consigui fazer o que eu queria! Eu desconhecia esse "weightSum". Se você por como resposta dou como resolvida!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/horizontalLinharLayout"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:weightSum="10"
              android:layout_width="math_parent"
              android:layout_height="math_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tx80Percent"
              android:layout_weight="8"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="0dp" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tx20Percent"
              android:layout_weight="2"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Lembrando que a soma dos `layout_weight` dentro do `LinearLayout` equivale à 100% (nesse caso 10), daí é só dividir de acordo. Já o `layout_width="0dp"` é para garantir que o `TextView` não vai tentar fazer outros cálculos em paralelo. Inclusive isso é mostrado como um *warning* no Android Studio.

Espero ter ajudado \o/

Comment: Podia acrescentar o atributo `weightSum`, que é uma otimização pro `LinearLayout` caso o peso dos filhos sejam fixos.

Comment: Feito! Não sabia dessa otimização do [`weightSum`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum)